# Delete Line GTK Keybinding

Tags: gtk, shortcut-keys

How do I bind a key combination (alt-backspace) to delete the current line of text? For example, `bind "<alt>Left" { "move-cursor" (display-line-ends, -1, 0) };` in gtk-keys.css moves the cursor to the beginning of the line (this works for me). (Using gtk 2/3 would be preferable, but other methods would be ok)
I want to delete the current line of text left of the cursor, NOT the paragraph to the left of the cursor.

```
bind "<alt>BackSpace" { "delete-from-cursor" (display-lines, -1) };
```

doesn't work. Pressing alt-Backspace does nothing, nor does `display-line-ends`.

```
bind "<alt>BackSpace" { "delete-from-cursor" (paragraph-ends, -1) };
```

deletes the paragraph to the left of the cursor.

I was thinking that I could select the text I want to delete (`"move-cursor" (display-line-ends, -1, 1)`) and delete it, but I can't figure out how to do the latter.

If anyone can direct me to resources listing gtk keybindings, I would be much obliged.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found that the line

```
bind "<alt>BackSpace" { "move-cursor" (display-line-ends, -1, 1) "delete-from-cursor" (chars, -1) };
```

works as I want it to.